# Pterodactyl HTTP Request in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, curl, swiftui

I spent hours trying to make an HTTP Request in SwiftUI using this API, but my progress equals zero. I need your help, guys

```
curl "https://pterodactyl.file.properties/api/client/account/api-keys/NWKMYMT2Mrav0Iq2" \
      -H 'Accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer apikey' \
```

I found this example on YouTube, but I don't know where and how to put the APIKey

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = [Result]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(results, id: \.trackId) { item in
                Text(item.trackName)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.collectionName)
            }
            .task {
                await loadData()
            }
        }
}
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have try a `URLSession` and `URLRequest`, no? The cURL is quite basic, so any try? Also, it's not related to `SwiftUI`, that is, as its name says for `UI`.

Comment: I did try with an example from youtube, but I don't know how and where to put the APIKey. I put the code in my question

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: your swift code shows the url for "https://itunes.apple.com...". You have copy and pasted the code from YouTube, and did not even change the url, and you expect to connect to a pterodactyl server? Is this all the efforts you have put into this try?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using

```
let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
```

You will need to get the data using a `URLRequest` object rather than from just the URL.  The code will look something like:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Bearer apiKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
```

Comment: Then it says to console

Testssss[23854:3318857] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics

Comment: That suggests that there is a lot more going on in your application that you have not shown us.  Copy and paste of code can only get you so far before you have to spend the time to understand what you've written. For HTTP communications you might start with the URLSession (or NSURLSession) documentation.